# How to get java command running?

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

When working with any command line (windows-cmd, git bash, ..), no Java commands are working.

I executed `java -version` and nothing happens. I can type again.

I have set my `JAVA_HOME` variable to `C:/Users/myName/Java/jdk1.8`

and I have also added `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to my `Path` variable.

It's not, that the command does not get recognised. It's just that nothing happens.
I could probably run the `java.exe` command directly, but I wanna fix the env variable.

Can someone help?

Best regards

[image]

Comment: [Please see why we shouldn't post images of text :)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Well first thing to check would be that you do have Java installed and that you CAN run the executable directly.

Comment: if you have updated your environment variables you will have to restart your cmd window(s) as well in order for the new environments variables to get in scope. You might even have to reboot the computer in some cases.

Comment: If you run `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and `echo %Path%` are they returning what you expect?

Comment: If `java` wouldnt be on the path, you would get something like "command cannot be found". Since it prints nothing, I is executing something. Possibly corrupted java installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Try this (Windows):

1. Locate your JDK/JRE binary - Usually the path for your JDK/JRE bin **(On Windows)** is:

   ***Your OS Drive(C or D etc):\Program Files\Java\jdk[version]\bin***. After you've located it, Copy your path to your clipboard.
2. Search for *"Environment Variables"* on windows.
3. Create a new ***User variable*** name it (usually named "*JAVA_HOME*") and copy your path as a value.

   [image]

   Now in ***System variables*** locate a variable named "*Path*" and add the same value set in *JAVA_HOME*.
4. Close and then reopen the CMD.

---

If this solution does not work, reinstall java. You can uninstall through:

***Control Panel -> Programs -> Under Programs and Features -> Uninstall a program.***

Comment: Seems like the problem was, that I also had another java version installed under C:\Programs Files\ and my JAV_HOME-variable was pointing to C:\Users\bla. After removing the installed version and adding JAVA_HOME to user variables, it is now working. Thank you InSaNiTy!